# How to make slide menu static or re-useable iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to make the slide menu re-useable without having to constantly add the same menu to every viewController in the menu drawer. How can I re-use, can I wrap all my view controllers within some type of main controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a new root view controller which contains the slide menu and also contains a container view that covers the entire size of the screen.

Within the container view you would embed your old root view controller.

The slide menu is now available to every view controller in your application and you can make it appear or disappear when you want by animating its frame origin to slide onto and off of the screen.

Comment: Ok this sounds reasonable now would I be able to add new buttons to the top right of the navigation bar on each view controller as well, or would it be blocked off because of the menu button?

Comment: Ignore that sentence I removed it, I am using xib files not a storyboard, and I am trying to understand how to add the container view exactly, should it be physically added on the xib file or is it suppose to be done programmatically, because I do not see it as an available view when looking at the xib file.

Comment: Can it be done programmatically? Or if storyboards are the better way to go, how do I go about transitioning a storyboard from a xib and vice versa?

Comment: Ok I am open to using storyboards, but is there a way to call upon it from a xib aka login controller which is using a xib file or should I just change everything into a storyboard

Comment: Yeah ok so I will take a look at storyboards and convert everything to that and take a swing at it. thanks for your help

Comment: So I transitioned into storyboards now and am using a container on the main but since I have a navigation controller wrapping the main it looks like a backbutton is created on the containers which is what I wanted to avoid since each of the slide menuitems should be the top level... How do I fix it so it is right below the navigation bar?

Comment: I tried your response but since I do not want to have you go through it through a chat I created a new question with the issues. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23158536/creating-a-slide-menu-with-story-boards-switch-error  your response worked well for being able to swipe but I get an error on the clicks now and the button doesnt appear.

Answer (score 0):

You could use AMSlideOutNavigation

https://github.com/andreamazz/SlideOutNavigation